# Compose Android - Update a Item from list without page refresh

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column, mutablestateof

I have a **LazyColumn** list which holds user Items and I have populated the list Item view no issue on that, in here say I need to update a view from the Item like updating the user profile picture **without updating the whole list** but just making the item that needs to be changed and not as whole page refresh.

Comment: Provide your code to understand the problem. Compose can recognize items that were changed and not touch the items that were not changed.